# Byte position of frame with closest timestamp with avprobe

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, libav

With ffprobe I managed to get the byte position of the frame closest to a specified timestamp: the `pkt_pos` in `ffprobe -i audio.mp3 -show_frames -read_intervals 01:30%+#1`. Now I am on a Debian system where ffmpeg is not available so I switched to libav-tools. Unfortunately, `avprobe -i audio.mp3 -show_frames -read_intervals 01:30%+#1` does not work as `read_intervals` is not available.
How do I solve the same task with libav instead of ffmpeg?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid the Libav knockoffs: just [download a static build of `ffprobe`](http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/) and use that instead, or [follow a guide to compile `ffprobe`](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu).

Comment: Hehe, I start to like this solution. I thought libav would be more or less synced with the state of ffmpeg, as they state to use the same syntax and stuff. After reading a bit about the history of the fork and all the steam about it, my initial assumption is rendered plain wrong. And ffmpeg seems active and on the way back to becoming a standard package again, so I guess it's fruitless to fight the inevitable.